# Advantages of inverted Delta, straight leading edge?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance

The advantages and features of a Delta wing have been very well described here, but this arrangement of an 'Inverted Delta' differs; also, it would be good knowing more about performance of a Canard foreplane with an ordinary and inverted Delta wing.